# How to list RPM dependencies?

Tags: centos, redhat, rpm, centos5, dependencies

Our production server is running CentOS release 5.2 (Final).

How do I see/get/list all the dependencies of an *already installed* RPM package?

For example: SQLite v3.3.6 is already installed in the server.  I want to see all the dependencies of this particular package.

Here is the output of the command: `rpm -qa |grep sqlite`

```
python-sqlite-1.1.7-1.2.1
sqlite-3.3.6-2
sqlite-3.3.6-2
```

Also, why it is listing 2 entries of `sqlite-3.3.6-2` here?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

1. `rpm -q --requires somepackagehere`
2. One is the `i?86` package, the other is the `x86_64` package.

Comment: My OS is 64-bit.  Can 2 architecture packages co-exist in the same server?  What is the purpose/need of having 2 architecture packages at the same time?

Comment: RH-/Fedora-derived distros support **multiarch**, whereby multiple packages belonging to "different-yet-similar-enough" archs can coexist in order to allow running executables built for either arch.

Comment: Unfortunately this requires the package to already be installed locally :\

Comment: @rogerdpack: Well, yes. That's exactly what the question asked for.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately google sends "everybody straight here" if you google "list RPM dependencies" -- google has scope creeped the question! Regardless, see davey's answer for any followers desiring that functionality.

Answer (score 39):

The `yum deplist` command will show you which **rpm**'s are dependencies, here's an example for the `expect` package (this will work even if you don't yet have the package installed locally):

```
# yum deplist expect
..
..
package: expect.i386 5.43.0-5.1
 dependency: libc.so.6
  provider: glibc.i686 2.5-49
  provider: glibc.i686 2.5-49
 dependency: libtcl8.4.so
  provider: tcl.i386 8.4.13-4.el5
```

Comment: This command is not working.  Am I missing something or there is something missing in your command?

Comment: Sorry there was a space missing, the command is yum deplist package.

Comment: +1 the use of YUM here is nice it's recursive and resolves things like 'perl(COnfig::Tiny)' or 'libc.so(64bit)'.

Answer (score 7):

Following on Ignacio's answer, you can see the specific architecture of the packages by doing the following:

```
$ rpm -qa --queryformat "%{NAME} %{ARCH}\n" sqlite
sqlite i686
```

In my case, I only have the one, i686 package...but you can get the architecture associated with the packages that way.  If you are interested in what else you can get from the --queryformat, issue a `rpm --querytags` to see the list of variables available.

Comment: +1 Your command on listing by architecture-wise is also helpful.

Answer (score 6):

People have already responded with:

1. `rpm -q --requires PKG`
2. `yum -q deplist PKG`

Yes, either `rpm` or `yum` works and correctly answers the question. The main difference between `rpm` and `yum` is that yum also shows what packages you can install to meet the library and/or file requirements. Unfortunately, if the package isn't installed, neither one of these methods are useful. Since the original poster already specified that the package you are checking is installed, this is a mute point.

What if you didn't have the package installed? `yum` can still be used, but indirectly. You can do a mock install by canceling the install operation.

```
printf n  |  yum install PKG  |  grep -- "---> Package"
```

Here is an example:

```
printf n  |  yum install php  |  grep -- "---> Package"
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.4.16-45.el7 will be installed
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.4.16-45.el7 will be installed
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.16-45.el7 will be installed
---> Package libzip.x86_64 0:0.10.1-8.el7 will be installed
```

Comment: Brilliant workaround to the reporting limitations.

Answer (score 3):

I have quick shell snippet which prints out all installed packages along with their dependencies:

```
for i in `rpm -qa` ; do echo "Package [$i]:"; rpm -q --requires $i ; echo ; done
```